# Is there a better way to display cpu usage in tmux?

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

Here's a solution which may consume a lot of cpu usage (stolen from [this article](http://makerwannabe.blogspot.co.nz/2011/04/showing-cpumemory-usage-on-tmux-status.html)):

There's a difference in my Ubuntu 12 ec2 server, I have to use `top -bn1` instead of `top -ln`.

Here's my related `.tmux.conf` file:

`set -g status-right '#[fg=yellow]#[(getCpuUsage.sh)]'`

It actually calls `top` every 2 seconds and outputs a whole lot of information.  I think there should be a way involving less cpu consumption or use some flag to limit the output of `top` to only cpu usage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use the small [tmux-mem-cpu-load](https://github.com/thewtex/tmux-mem-cpu-load) C++ program. It's at least one fork/exec per update either way, but probably better than invoking a shell.

Comment: Yes I try this,but it only give me memory usage

Answer (score 7):

If I knew tmux-mem-cpu-load, I would become too lazy to write my own [rainbarf](https://github.com/creaktive/rainbarf):

[image: rainbarf]

It has a fancier look, but it is a Perl script so it is not a good idea to run it every 2 seconds (on my experience, 15 seconds suffice).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `vmstat(1)`. It displays the averaged CPU load over all CPUs: user, system, idle and IO wait in the last four fields:

```
vmstat|while read s;do [[ "$s" =~ ([[:space:]]+[0-9]+){4}$ ]]&&echo $BASH_REMATCH; done
```

Comment: what exactly does this show?

Answer (score 1):

1. stat the command `top`
2. press 1.
3. Press 0 then
4. Press "t" twice.

It will display bar graphs of the CPU usage.
You can change the color by +z. Then choose a color number in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`htop` shows some decent display:

[image]

press F6 to choose sort-by-memory-usage